# Looking for a story about two kids trapped in a game and one dies

Tags: story-identification

There was this story I read ages ago when I was young, and I cant remember the title. It's probably based more for kids than adults, but it popped into my head and I want to remember it.

The story is about two boys who are inside a video game, where they have to shoot the enemies attacking them like an arcade shooter. They hide inside a cave on a cliff face, and the enemies lean over the top of the cliff to shoot at them, while the players peek out from the cave to shoot up. As they play, the two players hate each other more and more until the main character guy lets the other one get killed. The one that died returns as a powerful enemy with the ability to climb down the cliff face to enter the cave.

That's about all I can remember, but if anyone has an inkling as to what story I'm referring to, that would be lovely.

Comment: "[Jumanji](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113497/)" (1995)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of [Space Demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Demons), by [Gillian Rubinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillian_Rubinstein).

The two boys are school friends, one of whom's father brings home an experimental game that allows them to travel into the game to fight the eponymous Space Demons. Things go wrong and one of them is killed. The remaining boy enlists the help of the new girl in school and an older boy who had previously been antagonistic.

[image]

It's actually the first of a trilogy.

Comment: This was my guess. The original enemies in the game could only move in 2D, but once the first boy dies and becomes one of the enemies they "upgrade" and start moving in 3D which lets them get inside the previously safe cave.